# how to fix this issue / TS2740: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly ':

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vue-class-components

what are the solution that screenshot , how to do it
I want to know how to add  component to App.tsx file

[what are the solution that screenshot , how to do it

I want to know how to add  component to App.tsx file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQBt1.png)

```
import React from 'react';

interface Message {

}

interface MyState {
    message?: string,
    userName?: string
}

class Message extends React.Component<Message, MyState> {

    constructor(props: Readonly<any> | any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            message: 'welcome',
            userName: 'tashi'
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.message} {this.state.userName}</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Message;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import Greet from "./components/Greet";
import Message from "./components/Message";
import {Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
    return (
<div className="App">
<Message/>
</div>
);
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You aren't passing any props to `Message`.

Comment: you need to pas the props super expects, you are calling it in constructor, it probably expects those props that error lists and you are not giving them to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because both the class and props type called `Message`, simply rename any one if it to something else and it should works:

```
interface MessageProps {

}

class Message extends React.Component<MessageProps, MyState> {

    constructor(props: Readonly<MessageProps> | MessageProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            message: 'welcome',
            userName: 'tashi'
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

I also fix the type of constructor parameter to `Readonly<MessageProps> | MessageProps`